# What is anchor link that Github uses to link to a specific commit line?

Tags: github

I am trying to figure out what the anchor link (#diff- followed by an alphanumeric string and a line number) for specific file on a commit is, so I can generate links from an external system. Example:

https://github.com/facebook/react/commit/a37012a6b5fb5a1c0c19c962737189aeaebe3684#diff-7a9f2b48de4b0ffcf7b436798ce9aaabL67

This part: #diff-7a9f2b48de4b0ffcf7b436798ce9aaabR336 (the L67 refers to the line)?

Answer (score 1):

So a diff  is showing what a "head" commit changed, compared to a "base" commit.

The URL is basically `/commit/<HEAD>#diff-<BASE>L<Line>`

where `<BASE>` & `<HEAD>` are the commit's SHA hashes. As these can't contain "L" it's a good and safe indicator for the line number.

Comment: Say I have a file in a Github repository, how do I get the <BASE> and <HEAD> from the command line foreinstance? Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: You can use your git log for example:

    git log README.md
    commit 12abcd34
    Author Alice

        Fixed typos
    ...
    commit 09fe87
    Author Martin
        Adds the readme
```

If you want to know what typos Alice fixed, your `HEAD` is `12abcd34` and your `BASE` is `09fe87`

Comment: I am still having some trouble finding the `<BASE>` in the url `/commit/<HEAD>#diff-<BASE>L<Line>`. Foreinstance if I run `git clone https://github.com/reactjs/redux` and do a `git log`, I can easily see the <HEAD>. But I can see where or how I can generate the <BASE> part of the url? Foreinstance if I wanted to link to line 4 in the package.json file in this latest commit: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/commit/2d229f0e7b2d217a759d06486f3cbff153036a56#diff-b9cfc7f2cdf78a7f4b91a753d10865a2L4

Comment: I used `<HEAD>` and `<BASE>` as placeholders for the whatever two commit you wants to compare (that's what a diff is). They are the IDs of each commit you're comparing.

Comment: But I think perhaps the `diff-`part of the url https://github.com/reactjs/redux/commit/2d229f0e7b2d217a759d06486f3cbff153036a56#diff-b9cfc7f2cdf78a7f4b91a753d10865a2L4 is only a pattern, because you aren't comparing any per-se. My question is how I generate a link to a specific line on a git commit on github. :-)

Comment: Ahaa, so you don't want the diff, right!

Then the URL is `/blob/<commit id>/path/to/file#L123